# Git Branches For Tutorials

Tags: git, github, version-control

so I am trying to determine if this workflow is ideal and how to solve a common problem with it. Currently I have a completed project in my master branch of a git repo. What I need to do now is segment this project out into 20 "chapters". Each chapter represents some progress that takes me from a completely empty project at chapter 1 to the complete project I now have at chapter 20. Ideally, the repo branches would be:

Master
Chapter1
...
Chapter20 (which is similar to Master in that the project is complete)

Does this seem like a reasonable way to structure it? Furthermore, as I am making changes, I'd like to know how to make a common commit to all branches in the event that I forget something. An example would be if on chapter 10, I realize there is something I missed that should have existed in chapter 2. I can go back and add it to chapter 2, but then I'd like it added to 3 through 10 to represent that change having been there the whole time. Is that possible?

Thank you

Comment: I have seen books where the chapters are unrelated stories. And many books that have some chronological order between the chapters. How will your book look like on this scale? Why do you think you need branches? Will someone else work on the book at the same time?

Comment: It's not a book per se, we are just calling the steps "chapters". Each chapter builds off of the previous one. Thus chapter 2 is chapter 1 plus additional changes. There are other people working on this and they need to be able to jump to any chapter at random to work on the documentation

Comment: It sounds like `tags` will be more appropriate than `branches`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick with a branch for each chapter, then your approach is a possibility. It depends on your actual needs and document/project structure. But if you change sth. in (branch) "chapter2" you have to merge it into all the following chapters (child branches), i.e.

```
git checkout chapter2;
# edit chapter2.txt, git add, git commit
git checkout chapter3; git merge chapter2;
git checkout chapter4; git merge chapter3;
...
git checkout chapter20; git merge chapter19;
```

---

Update: If you want your chapters completely independent of each other, you can also use git's ***octopus*** merge. That's a merge of more than one branch into the current one. From what you've described I wouldn't recommend it but just show you:

You would then have 20 branches chapter1 ... chapter20 which *do not* depend on each other, i.e. chapter2 is *not* "chapter1 + edits", it's only chapter2. Every branch handles (and sees) only its own chapter, nothing else. Then, when you want to release a new book, you would do

```
git checkout master
git merge chapter1 chapter2 chapter3 ... chapter20
```

The branch *master* is then the merge of all chapters. This yields to funny pictures in `gitk`, thus the name *octopus* ;-)

The downside is, *branchX* cannot depend on any changes in the other branches. As said, it depends on the situation whether this makes sense for you.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was assuming, but I wasn't sure if that was a dumb way to do it or if there was an easier way. I am trying this now and it seems to be working alright.

Comment: No, it's in no way dumb. Like @Gavriel said in his answer: it's a normal workflow in software development except the branches are called "feature branch" there. featureN+1 is featureN + changes. If your situation is like this, then it's just perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The scenarios you described are similar to "standard" software development when you use so called feature branches. You will need to merge your chapter branches to master and then everyone will need to merge from master to the chapter branch(es) they work on. You'll have some conflicts probably when someone will need to change an older chapter, but it still looks possible.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `tags` will be more appropriate than `branches`. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/165725/git-branching-and-tagging-best-practices might provide some insight for you. I originally asked this in terms of a professional project, but I think the same ideas equally apply to a tutorial.